# How to properly set up heavy work in concurrency?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, concurrency, concurrent-ruby

There are 1 million customers. I need to send them in batches to a third-party service, get a response and process. the same code for 500_000 customers works.

```
thread_pool = Concurrent::FixedThreadPool.new(100)

executors = customers.each_slice(150).map do |batch|
  Concurrent::Future.execute(executor: thread_pool) do
    # hard work
  end
end
```

This code does not work, crashes or with an error `can't create Thread: Resource temporarily unavailable`. Or crashes with an error `137` (by memory) from **k8s**, when I work in the terminal.

How can I optimize my work with concurrent?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem you are trying to solve? What do you mean by "send customers to a service"? Like redirecting on a website? Or do you send out emails? Do you load all customers into memory at once and therefore run out of memory? Did you try `find_each` or  `in_batches`?

Comment: customers are a array of hashes `[{email: '', msisdn: '', values: ''}, ...]`. 150 clients is the third-party service limit. I use `each_slice`